# Prove that $G_a$ has a hamilton circuit

Tags: graph-theory

So I need some help with this problem.

I thought I used the right theorem but dont think so.

Here is my try:
We have graph G, $a\in$ **N** and define $G_a$:

- $V(G_a)=\{(x,p):v\in V(G), 1\leq p\leq a\}$
- $\{u,v\}\in E(G), 1\leq p\leq a \iff \{(u,p),(v,p)\}\in E(G_a)$ and $v\in V(G), 1\leq p\leq a-1 \iff \{(v,p),(v,p+1)\} \in E(G_a)$.

Prove that $G_a$ has a hamilton circuit if $3\leq |G|$ and G has such a circuit

My attempt:
I know by a theorem that if G is a graph and $|G|=n\leq 3$ and $\delta(G)\leq n/2$. So first of all $3\leq |G_a|$. I know want to prove that $\delta(G_a)\geq n/2$. How can I proceed?

Comment: Are you sure you mean $\vert G \vert\leq 3$? I think the only hamiltonian graph satisfying this is the triangle $C_3$...

Comment: Yes I wrote the wrong symbols, thanks for noticing! I've edited now @PrudiiArca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Revised to get a Hamiltonian *circuit*.**

You can describe a Hamiltonian path in $G_a$ directly. Think of $G_a$ as a vertical stack of $a$ copies of $G$, with vertical edges between corresponding vertices in adjacent copies. Let $P$ be a Hamiltonian cycle $v_0v_1\ldots v_nv_0$in $G$.

Start at vertex $\langle v_0,1\rangle$ in the top copy and trace the path in that copy to $\langle v_n,1\rangle$. Drop down to the $\langle v_n,2\rangle$ in the second copy and trace it in reverse, but only as far as $\langle v_1,2\rangle$. Drop down to $\langle v_1,3\rangle$ in the third copy and trace it forward to $\langle v_n,3\rangle$. Continue in this fashion.

If $a$ is odd, you’ll trace the path forward in level $a$, ending at $\langle v_n,a\rangle$, and you can complete the circuit by going from there to $\langle v_0,a\rangle$ and then straight up through the vertices $\langle v_0,k\rangle$ until you finish back at $\langle v_0,1\rangle$.

If $a$ is even, you’ll trace the path in reverse in level $a$, ending at $\langle v_1,a\rangle$, and you can complete the circuit by going to $\langle v_0,a\rangle$ and then straight up through the vertices $\langle v_0,k\rangle$ until you finish back at $\langle v_0,1\rangle$.

Comment: This works for a Hamiltonian path; it doesn't quite work for a Hamiltonian cycle.

Comment: @MishaLavrov: True, but a graph is Hamiltonian if it has a Hamiltonian path, and when I wrote this answer, the question was to show that $G_a$ is Hamiltonian if $G$ is. Now the question has been changed.

Comment: Not by any terminology I've encountered! Usually, graphs with Hamiltonian paths are called "traceable". [Wikipedia agrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path#Definitions), though I realize it's not the final arbiter of such things.

Comment: @MishaLavrov: It’s been a long time since I did much with graph theory, so you’re very likely right about the terminology. It can still be done, but I'll have to rewrite it.

Comment: How can we know that these copies is connected by edges?

Comment: @Linelina: Because the description of $G_a$ says that $\langle v,k\rangle$ and $\langle v,k+1\rangle$ are connected by an edge for every $k\in\{1,\ldots,a-1\}$. Those are the vertical edges in the picture that I’m suggesting.